# Instantiate a prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am making a crossy road game with 4 prefab "chunks" that I want to create when the player touches the collider named . My code randomizes which chunk is loaded when the player hits it and then spawns the next chunk. For some reason though, it doesn't recognize my prefab and I want to load the chunk 25 z-value ahead of the last one. Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class ChunkLoader : MonoBehaviour {
int level = 0;
public Transform chickenpos;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void spawnChunk()
{
    float chunkload = Random.Range(0, 2);
    Debug.Log(chunkload);
    if (level <= 10)
    {
        if(chunkload <= 1 )
        {

         Instantiate  (ChunkA1, chickenpos);

        }
    } 

}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Loader")
    {
        level = level++;
        Debug.Log(level);
        spawnChunk();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This does **not** describe your problem well but you seem to be referencing a variable(`ChunkA1`) that is not even declared.

Comment: In that case, I will refer you to [C# tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting). See the **Variables and Functions** topic.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to declare a variable for your prefab - I will assume it is of type Gameobject here.

```
int level = 0;
public Transform chickenpos;
public Gameobject ChunkA1; //declare variable for the prefab

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {}
```

You can then either drag the prefab in your Assets folder to the field in the inspector, or locate it through your script using `Resources.Load()`.

Comment: @wizviper It is not clear what effect you are trying to achieve with the z-values, if you clarify we can try to help out. Are you trying to instantiate all 4 prefabs at once?